# PCIE NVME version 4.0 behaving like PCIE NVME version 1.0

Tags: ssd, pci-express

I had a new [HP Desktop](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/victus-by-hp-15l-gaming-desktop-pc-tg02-0000a/2101006743/model/2101006752/document/c08107471) for my son which came with 512GB of PCIE NVME SSD. Specs of [HP Desktop](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/victus-by-hp-15l-gaming-desktop-pc-tg02-0000a/2101006743/model/2101006752/document/c08107471) 512 GB is too less - I replaced it with a old Dell XPS laptop(2018)-1 TB PCIE NVME(as that laptop was dead now due to mother board issue). 1 TB PCIE NVME - samsung worked fine but it was slow and not spacious. So I purchased this [one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0B25M8FXX). It was suppose to be having 5000 MBPS read and more than 3000 MBPS write speed. I had tested this in another computer and specs were right.

But in this computer, it's only giving very less speed.
[image]

Did everything possible-Windows 11 optimize and defrag but the results are the same. BIOS is updated and device driver is also updated.
I used [Macrium](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) to do the disk clonning.
Is there some correlation as Macrium did sector by sector copy and that's why the version 4.0 PCIE NVME behaving the same as old version 1.0 PCIE NVME?
I have no idea what to do?

HP Desktop is under warranty but HP support is really awful.

The same drive in [Dell desktop(2017)](https://www.hardware-corner.net/desktop-models/Dell-XPS-8930/) is running fine-at good speed
[image]

Crucial website states that HP desktop is compatible with this [drive](https://www.crucial.com/ssd/p3-plus/ct4000p3pssd8/CT22138595)

As per HP Desktop motherboard

```
One PCI Express Gen 3.0 x16
One PCI Express Gen 3.0 x1
Two M.2 expansion slots
One M.2 socket 1, Key A
One M.2 socket 3, Key M, (2280/2242)
```

Processor is AMD Ryzen 7 5700G. 32 GB DDR4-3200 Mhz RAM(2 X 16 GB) plus AMD Radeon RX 6600 XT Graphics(8 GB GDDR6 dedicated)

As per google search
The AMD Ryzen 7 5700G supports up to PCIe 3.0. It has 20 lanes of PCIe 3.0 connectivity, with 16 lanes for the graphics slot, four for the CPU-connected M.2 NVMe slot, and four for the chipset bus.

[image]

Found a very interesting and detailed thread [here](https://linustechtips.com/topic/1406213-m2-nvme-ssd-uses-wrong-transfer-mode/)

Will this [item](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07JKH5VTL) help?

Comment: Which test was it? The documentation says "up to 5000MB/s **sequential** reads, **random** read/write 650K/900K IOPS". Your test results seem like a mixture of both kinds, random and sequential.

Comment: First 2 are sequential and last 2 are random seek/write

Comment: Depending on what else is connected or which slot the drive is in it may only be operating at with two lanes (x2) of PCIe, which would explain the roughly 2GB/s. Your should check your manual and see if you have another slot that the drive can go in. The B550 motherboard should have a PCIe 4.0 slot connected to the CPU, but there might be a second slower slot connected to the motherboard chipset.

Answer (score 1):

Your results are similar in some aspects but slower in others,
compared to those in the post
[B550M-A PRO M.2 speed too slow](https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?threads/b550m-a-pro-m-2-speed-too-slow.382641/):

[image]

The poster than changed his M.2 disk from patriot P300
to Kingston FURY Renegade PCIe 4.0 NVMe and got these results:

[image]

The final answer he got was that these results now max out his
PCI-E 3.0 connection.

Conclusion : You may improve the disk speed by buying a higher-end SSD,
but this motherboard is just incapable of reaching the rated 5000 MB/s,
unless perhaps in laboratory conditions.

You haven't specified your CPU, because that can be another limiting
factor, but there is no point in investing that much in this computer.

Comment: The P3 SSDs also use HMB, which may be reliant on CPU memory bandwidth and if OP only has single channel RAM then that may have an effect.

Comment: I have 32 GB RAM - two slots both being filled.